# Compute the Zariski-closure of two sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Compute the Zariski-closure of the following two sets:

1. $X = \{(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \mid |z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 = 1\}$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$.
2. $X = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid z = n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: and your thoughts are?

Comment: Well, it seems like the first set is already closed, since it is an algebraic set. It also seems like the second set is already closed, since it consists of isolated points. However, I'm not particularly used to working with the Zariski topology.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the second set is closed. Perhaps the Zariski-closure is then all of $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding 2: We define $Z \subset \mathbb{C}$ to be closed if $Z = V(S)$ for some $S \subset \mathbb{C}[x]$.  Since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, it is a PID, so $S$ generates a principal ideal, i.e., $(S) = (f)$ for some $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.  Then every point in $V(S) = V(f)$ is a root of $f$, but $f$ has at most $\operatorname{deg}(f) = n$ distinct roots.  This shows that every proper algebraic set in $\mathbb{C}$ is finite.  Thus, the Zariski-closure of $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \;|\; z = n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subset \mathbb{C}$ must not be a proper subset, so it's $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

The first set isn't Zariski closed either. A proper Zariski-closed set would be a contained in the zero locus of a bivariate polynomial. Thus (at least at non-singular points) it locally looks like a 1-dimensional complex manifold, i.e. a 2-dimensional real manifold. But this set is a 3-dimensional real manifold, and thus we don't expect it to be contained in a proper Zariski-closed subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Let $P(Z_1,Z_2)$ be a polynomial that vanishes on all of $X$. Let $z_0$ be an arbitrary complex number with the property $|z_0|<1$. The univariate polynomial
$$
F(Z_2)=P(z_0,Z_2)
$$
vanishes whenever $|z_2|=\sqrt{1-|z_0|^2}$. Therefore it has infinitely many zeros. This is possible for a univariate polynomial only, if it is the zero polynomial. Thus we can conclude that $Z_1-z_0\mid P(Z_1,Z_2)$. But there are infinitely many distinct such numbers $z_0$. This implies that $\deg P(Z_1,Z_2)$ exceeds any bound unless it is the zero polynomial. So the zero polynomial is the only polynomial vanishing on $X$. Hence the Zariski-closure of $X$ is all of $\mathbb{C}^2.$

Comment: @Lahtonen  Does the same argument works to show that the following set is  Zariski dense;We  Identify $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$  with $\mathbb{C}^{n^{2}}$. Our set is all  matrix with unit operator norm.